# Golang ending (Binance) web service stream using go routine

Tags: go, event-handling, goroutine, binance, binance-api-client

I'm integrating Binance API into an existing system and while most parts a straight forward, the data streaming API hits my limited understanding of go-routines. I don't believe there is anything special in the golang SDK for Binance, but essentially I only need two functions, one that starts the data stream and processes events with the event handler given as a parameter and a second one that ends the data stream without actually shutting down the client as it would close all other connections. On a previous project, there were two message types for this, but the binance SDK uses an implementation that returns two go channels, one for errors and an another one, I guess from the name, for stopping the data stram.

The code I wrote for starting the data stream looks like this:

```
func startDataStream(symbol, interval string, wsKlineHandler futures.WsKlineHandler, errHandler futures.ErrHandler) (err error){

    doneC, stopC, err := futures.WsKlineServe(symbol, interval, wsKlineHandler, errHandler)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

This works as expected and streams data. A simple test verifies it:

```
func runWSDataTest() {
    symbol := "BTCUSDT"
    interval := "15m"
    errHandler := func(err error) {fmt.Println(err)}

    wsKlineHandler := func(event *futures.WsKlineEvent) {fmt.Println(event)}

    _ = startDataStream(symbol, interval, wsKlineHandler, errHandler)
}
```

The thing that is not so clear to me, mainly due to incomplete understanding, really is how do I stop the stream. I think the returned stopC channel can be used to somehow issue a end singnal similar to, say, a sigterm on system level and then the stream should end.

Say, I have a stopDataStream function that takes a symbol as an argument

```
func stopDataStream(symbol){

}
```

Let's suppose I start 5 data streams for five symbols and now I want to stop just one of the streams. That begs the question of:

1. How do I track all those stopC channels?
2. Can I use a collection keyed with the symbol, pull the stopC channel, and then just issue a signal to end just that data stream?
3. How do I actually write into the stopC channel from the stop function?

Again, I don't think this is particularly hard, it's just I could not figure it out yet from the docs so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer originally written by [@Marvin.Hansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1905726/marvin-hansen))

Turned out, just saving & closing the channel solved it all. I was really surprised how easy this is, but here is the code of the updated functions:

```
func startDataStream(symbol, interval string, wsKlineHandler futures.WsKlineHandler, errHandler futures.ErrHandler) (err error) {

    _, stopC, err := futures.WsKlineServe(symbol, interval, wsKlineHandler, errHandler)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    // just save the stop channel 
    chanMap[symbol] = stopC
    return nil
}
```

And then, the stop function really becomes embarrassing trivial:

```
func stopDataStream(symbol string) {
    stopC := chanMap[symbol]  // load the stop channel for the symbol
    close(stopC) // just close it. 
}
```

Finally, testing it all out:

```
var (
    chanMap map[string]chan struct{}
)

func runWSDataTest() {
    chanMap = make(map[string]chan struct{})

    symbol := "BTCUSDT"
    interval := "15m"
    errHandler := func(err error) { fmt.Println(err) }
    wsKlineHandler := getKLineHandler()

    println("Start stream")
    _ = startDataStream(symbol, interval, wsKlineHandler, errHandler)

    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    println("Stop stream")
    stopDataStream(symbol)

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

This is it.